# El teclado no aparece en mi DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Tengo un DialogFragment donde al abrirlo tiene un boton para añadir un item con dos EditText. Al tocar los EditText no me aparece el teclado.

Este es el codigo que uso en onCreateAlertDialog

```
private AlertDialog crearDialogoModificarEjercicio() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialogo_modificar_ejercicio_rutina, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    btAnadirSerie = v.findViewById(R.id.btAnadirSerie);
    layoutSeries = v.findViewById(R.id.layoutAnadirSeries);
    tvNombre = v.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreEjercicioDialog);
    tvDescripcion = v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcionEjercicioDialog);
    ivImagenEjercio = v.findViewById(R.id.ivImagenEjercicioDialog);
    fabConfirmarAjustesEjercicio = v.findViewById(R.id.fabConfirmarConfiguracionEjercicio);

    listaRepeticiones = new ArrayList();
    listaPesos = new ArrayList();


    btAnadirSerie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            totalSeries += 1;
            int id = (R.layout.item_anadir_serie);
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);

            layoutSeries.addView(constraintLayout);
        }
    });

    fabConfirmarAjustesEjercicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            guardarListas();
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Y así llamo al dialog

```
DialogoModificarEjercicioRutinaFragment dialogoModificarEjercicioRutinaFragment = new DialogoModificarEjercicioRutinaFragment();
            dialogoModificarEjercicioRutinaFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogoModificarEjercicio");
```

Revisé algunas soluciones que encontré pero lo de softInput no me funciona, si lo añado al crear al dialog el teclado me aparece detras de de ese dialog, y si se lo pongo a los edittext no hace nada

EDIT:

Este es el EditText en mi xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNumeroRepeticiones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvRepeticiones"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
```

En los EditText ya intenté poner las opciones de focuseable a true pero no funciona.

En el manifest la activity que tiene el DialogFragment no tiene ninguna propiedad especificada:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.rutinas.AnadirRutinaActivity" />
```

Comment: Como esta definido el EditText  en tu layout? la Activity en tu AndroidManifest.xml que propiedades tiene?

Comment: @Jorgesys ya actualicé la publicación con lo que me pides, las propiedades de la activity que me pides me imagino que sería de la que contiene el DialogFragment.